# Monerod finished syncing but now never catches up in GUI wallet, monerod still syncing

Tags: blockchain

I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit, on a crummy burner laptop.
So monerod finally finished syncing last week and I followed advice here and opened the GUI wallet, it was all syncing together as it should but literally only for about an hour - after that monerod never stopped adding blocks, coming up with the 'new top block candidate' message.
I had to leave it overnight and when I came back it was way out again, only by 7 days but that's eons on my old machine and slow connection. It's been the same for a week now, it never catches up to the top block and the wallet constantly says syncing to the daemon.
What am I doing wrong? I just want to use my wallet but this is about 4 weeks building it now. Everything has gone right, just that it's taken forever to do so. 
Because it was synced at one point is it ok/safe to use now? Or do I have to keep waiting for it to fully sync with that never-attainable top block?
Thanks for the help, really appreciated, and my apologies if this has been answered but I can't find the answer to this on here, maybe I'm being blind or stupid or both. I am useless at this stuff, I've followed the guides here and reddit to get this far with a lot of trial and error, never fully understanding what I'm actually doing. Yep, it's bad...
Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried restarting the GUI and daemon? Also, could you post the full output of `Show status` (on the `Settings` page of the GUI)?

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: 
cd ~/Downloads/monero-gui-0.10.3.1-beta2

Step 2: 
wget -c --progress=bar https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw

Step 3: I
./monero-blockchain-import --guard-against-pwnage 0 --input-file ./blockchain.raw

Step 4: 
rm -rf ./blockchain.raw

Step 5: 
./monerod --detach

Comment: The current version is v0.12.0.0. If you use anything older than that you will sync to the wrong (alternative) chain.

Comment: As dEBRUYNE commented, version in this answer is wrong. Further, the OP already has a near fully synchronized chain, so just needs latest binaries.